# Flutter Web App Weird Beahvior in Desktop View on Mobile Phone

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am making a website with flutter

[codingfries.com](https://codingfries.com)

Can someone check what the hell is happening when I click on Desktop View on chrome browser in mobile phone. The website starts to behave weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to happen as the layout changes. Width of screen changes when you emulate Desktop view on mobile phone. For handling such cases, flutter has media queries which can be used to change layouts based on screen size changes.
For more info refer the official documentation.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive

Comment: Secondly it should resize but the widget disappears for some reason lol

Comment: I looked at your website and the widgets you said disappeared just went up, like above the viewport

Comment: No it did not actually go up .. umm it's there but not visually lol .. idk how to explain this but if u open the website in a web browser .. you can see that the orange button is in the upper right corner .. and keeping that place in mind .. when u open the website in desktop view on phone .. click that place and you'll see that it actually clicks the button but the button is not there visually .. idk why this is happening srsly .. I have another website that doesn't have a problem in desktop view .. idk why this one has